# willTransitionToState and didTransitionToState not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell in which I have the method willTransitionToState and didTransitionToState in it, however it is not getting called when I try to swipe on the cell. Why is this?

Comment: Does it get called when you put the whole table view in editing mode?

Comment: yes it does get called when I set the cell.editing to YES manually in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

Your table view data source has to implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For swipe-to-delete to work. Does it?